# PWA Support for IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps

I'm researching a solution to having PWA support for IE11. Support for Service Workers plus PWA as a whole. I'm using Vue2 for UI. Ideally I'm looking for polyfil package(s). Web results are limited. Any suggestions or pointers for fullstack PWA support?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Service Worker API is not supported in IE11 https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_serviceworker it is not possible to use PWA features there. And I am afraid there is no polyfill available for that because service workers (scripts that run independently of a web page) are the part of the browser functionality, not the part of the web app.

What you can do is to detect if Service Worker is available in the browser `if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {}` then register Service Worker. If not then you app will work as an ordinary website without PWA features.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the [ServiceWorker API still not support IE browser](https://caniuse.com/#search=service%20worker) now, and I'm not find an polyfill to make service worker support IE browser. I suggest you could check this article: [What Browsers Support Service Workers?](https://love2dev.com/blog/what-browsers-support-service-workers/).

If the browser not support Service Worker and no polyfill, you might consider to cache website assets in localStorage. And if you want to use service worker to push notifications and background sync APIs, you could try to use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms)(It is an open-source library for developers that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications, and it support IE browser)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need offline support in IE11 you could try using [AppCache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache). It's deprecated though and shouldn't be used on modern browsers.